# CSS Invalid selector not working with reactive form

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm facing a problem where i cannot bind :invalid css selector with my input since i have custom validation. invalid is only active with basic validator example: input type="email" so the invalid will work with example@ or example@example.exmaple while my function only validates the last one (example@example.example).
[Project Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nedzmt?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&view=preview)

> HTML FILE

```
<input class="custom-input" type="email" [(ngModel)]='Email' name="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="emailTxt">
<div class="err>
   this is an error
</div>
```

> TypeScript File

```
this.signUpForm = this._fb.group({
   emailTxt: [null, Validators.compose([
     Validators.required
   ])]
 }, {
     validators: [
       EmailValidation('emailTxt'),
     ]
   });
```

> Form Validation Function

```
export function EmailValidation(controlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];

    if (control.errors && !control.errors.invalidEmail) {
      return;
    }
    if (control.value.trim().match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{1,5}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/) == null) {
      control.setErrors({ invalidEmail: true });
    }
    else {
      control.setErrors(null);
    }
  }
}
```

> CSS File

```
.custom-input:invalid{
    & ~ .err {
      max-height: 200px;
      padding: 0 18px 10px 20px;
      color: red;
    }
}
```

i expect the invalid selector should to be triggered with every control.setErrors() function

Comment: where is the working example of it ?

Comment: Hello Just updated the question link in description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below CSS code in your project, that's definitely works

```
input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: **Thank you so much**

Answer (score 0):

This will work Definitely ☺ add to ur css file

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched, select.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: +1 this actually works if i want to show the error message on focus out, it actually helps thank you for your answer.